# java: ClassNotFoundException for com.isomorphic.servlet.DataSourceLoader entry in web.xml

Tags: java, web-applications, web.xml, smartgwt, classnotfoundexception

I have specified in web.xml Servlet mapping as below

```
    <web-app>
        <!-- Servlets -->
            <servlet>
                     <servlet-name>DataSourceLoader</servlet-name>
                     <servlet-class>com.isomorphic.servlet.DataSourceLoader</servlet-class>
            </servlet>
    </web-app>
```

In classpath, reference to corresponding jar file is present, also class is shown in referenced libraries listing in package explorer. But still when i run this web application, its give exception of class not found.

Am i missing entry in some file?

Web application is smartGWT based.

Comment: where you have kept your jar file ? and can you double check by exploring jar file for this class

Comment: error pretty much ensures that WEB-INF/lib is not having the jar.

Comment: @org.life.java - Jigar Joshi:  jar file is in projectname/lib folder. I have checked class exist in jar.

Comment: @Nishant: jar file is not part of  WEB-INF/lib. Is it necessary to have it in same folder or lib folder of project i.e. projectname/lib is fine?

Comment: your app server will look into WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib for that Class (or the Jar). Better it be in either of these two folders.

Comment: @Maddy yes keep it in WEB-INF/lib as @Nishant has suggested

Comment: @Nishant: classes in that jar file are also referred by src code which is not part of web-inf. So to avoid having two copies of jar what should i do?

Comment: well. Do not worry, if the Jar is in WEB-INF/lib it is visible to your SRC folder as well. Your SRC folder will finally be compiled and copied to WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Thanks guys. Issue is resolved.

Comment: @Maddy.Shik I have compiled an answer aggregating the comments here. You may want to mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. So, I will just write it down.

**Problem**

The problem was, your app server was not able to find the Jar that has this class named `com.isomorphic.servlet.DataSourceLoader`

**Hint**

ClassNotFound ensures that the class is not in classpath. Or in other way, the Jar or the class file is somewhere the app-server does not look for.

**Solution**

App server looks, at least, in WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes for the Classes or the Jars that might have classes that are being imported somewhere. Now, the Jars in WEB-INF/libs are also available to the code written inside SRC directory (which finally gets compiles and the .class files are copied to WEB-INF/classes directory.

The solution was putting the Jar in WEB-INF/lib directory.